# Modifying the title of duplicate questions

Tags: discussion, editing, exact-duplicates, title

[This question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/review/close/207243) was recently closed as duplicate. I agree with this, but the title is now the title of the older question which is more restrictive than that of the new one (the old one is about two groups, the new one is about a collection).

What should be done in cases like this? Should we edit the title of the old question?

Comment: I don't see the accepted answer in the old question saying anything about more than 2 groups.

Comment: In that case, the questions should be unmerged.

Comment: Jonas commented that it is easily extended to multiple groups, is that incorrect?

Answer (score 7):

The question's an old one with a correct, clear, accepted answer that applies to the more general case, so I think we can be bold in editing; it's got many views, & duplicates linking to it, so I think we should be.

Comment: Hmm. Does whuber's answer explicitly apply to the case of more than 2 groups?